# could not apply the stored config for monitors - 14.04 update

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, lts, stable-release-updates

Last night the auto update file was downloaded and when it was through I turned off my computer. This morning on booting up and signing in I get the Could not update message the rest of which reads:
None of the Selected modes were compatible with possible modes Trying modes CRTC80 with 2 more lines of different screen resolutions.
When I close the window, that all that happens. The mouse pointer goes away and the nothing else happens.
Re-booting to the command prompt I can remove monitors.xml but all that does is remove the error message so that as soon as I log in nothing happens.
Running a NVidia G86 GeForce 8500 GT card.
Since everything freezes and the only access I have is the command prompt (which I'm not very good as using) my options to fix this are limited.